# Calculating $W$ - $Z$ bosons mass difference

Tags: particle-physics, mass, standard-model, higgs, electroweak

Naively one might expect the W weak vector bosons to have slightly higher mass than the Z due to EM self-energy, while the opposite is true (80 vs. 91 Gev). Presumably due to the strong interactions and mediated by quarks since that is the only particle coupled to both interactions, but I can't find a discussion of this, even qualitative, anywhere.  Anyone aware of any?

Plenty of recent papers relating to the ATLAS and CMS measurements of the W mass, but none seem to touch this point.  And of course the pions do agree with the naive assumption but the kaons don't, so perhaps all that can be said was said so long ago that it doesn't come up in todays' searches.  The percent difference is much greater in the vector boson case though, than for the mesons.

Comment: W and Z get their masses from coupling with the Higgs field, that's why the couplings g and g' occur in Cosmas' formula.

Comment: Don’t confuse the *Z* with ${{W}_{3}}$ the partner of ${{W}_{\pm }}$.  The ${{W}_{3}}$ mixes with a “pre-photon” *Y* that couples to weak hypercharge to yield the photon and *Z* as we know them.

Answer (score 3):

No, absolutely not! Naively, one might expect $M_W=M_Z ~ \cos \theta_W < M_Z$, where $\theta_W=   \arccos \frac{g}{\sqrt{g^2+g'^2}}$  is the [weak mixing angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinberg_angle), at the heart of the logic of the  [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model_(mathematical_formulation)#The_Higgs_mechanism)!

Geometrically, $M_W$ is the base and $M_Z$ the hypotenuse of the SM  coupling space right triangle,[image]

*g* being the su(2) coupling and *g'* the hypercharge coupling. The hypotenuse is always larger than the base. In our world this Weinberg angle is almost 30°.

In a hypothetical alternative world with very small Weinberg angle, the electric charge *e* would be essentially the hypercharge and then the Z would be only slightly heavier than the W.

I'm not quite sure what you could have in mind w.r.t. EM self-energy of a neutral object, or with strong corrections; there are heavy quark loop and Higgs radiative corrections to both gauge boson propagators, but they are *small*! The dominant tree-level result here is what it is: an experimental number fixed by the EM charge *e* and the *g* implicit in the Fermi constant of *β* decay, $\theta_W=   \arcsin e/g$. Given these couplings, the mass ratio expected in the model is fixed, and, of course, validated just right by observation.

Comment: My intuition was that the EM self-energy of the W's (compared to none for the Z) should give it slightly *higher* mass if they are truly elementary particles, without internal structure, in an admittedly *very* naive model.  Since the weak mixing angle is calculated from the mass ratio, it doesn't seem to *explain* or motivate that counter-intuitive situation for me, other than perhaps that they can't be more than equal, not W > Z, by that formulation.

Comment: Sorry, you got it wrong: I am explaining in the last paragraph that the mass ratio is a *prediction* based on the measured sin θ = e/g, g being traceable to $G_F$. There is *no* freedom left over in the SM as far as this is concerned. That's the whole *point* of the extraordinary triumph of the SM, and, normally, at the top of the items in the teaching thereof!